# How to download partial document data in Android Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have my database on Cloud Firestore.
The data is read-only.
And the client application is an Android App written in Kotlin.

My database is something like this:

```
collection{courses}
    document{doc1}
        name: "csn206"
        ...
        ...
    document{doc2}
        name: "csn207"
        ...
        ...
    document{doc3}
        name: "csn301"
        ...
        ...
```

I am trying to access my data in this way:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("courses")
db
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener{
        // display list of documents
    }
```

But, this downloads everything.
I want reduce the unnecessary usage of Internet.

So, what I want to do is display `name` values of all documents in a list.
And select the documents which are needed to be downloaded completely.

So, my question is how to get list of all documents' `name` values, without getting all of the documents?